# Pidgin says "Unable to add user: Unknown error (204)" on login to MSN

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin, windows-live-messenger

I have Pidgin 6.5.5 for Ubuntu 9.04.

Whenever I login to my MSN account, I get this error:

```
"Unable to add user: Unknown error (204)" on login to MSN
```

Which shows up in the debug log as:

```
(18:22:45) blist: Updating buddy status for someuser@email.com (MSN)
(18:22:45) msn: ADL error
```

Where `email.com` is not just yahoo.com, like many misguided forum posts say.

I have tried the following:

1. Removing all references to any @yahoo.com buddies for this MSN account
2. Removing all references to any buddies that cause the ADL error. After each successive removal, another buddy causes the error.

The [bug](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/8988) even says its fixed in version 6.5.0, but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took more than a year of not bothering to figure this out, but I finally figured it out.

**Do these things:**

1. Log in to MSN on a Windows box. (I know, it hurt me too)
2. Find that user, and delete them, their account is probably closed anyway
3. Your Pidgin should work fine again.

I couldn't for the life of me fix this problem with Pidgin alone.